# Show that if $p(x) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $p(a) = f'(a)$ then $p'(a) = \dfrac{f''(a)}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

According to the lecturer we are meant to use the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to answer this.  So I know that $ \dfrac {f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \dfrac {[f(b)-f(a)]}{[g(b)-g(a)]} $.  However, I am still unsure how to use this to prove the that $ p'(a) = \dfrac {f''(a)}{2} $.

Could someone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{p(a+\delta)-p(a)}{\delta}=\frac{\frac{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}{\delta}-f'(a)}{\delta}.
$$
As $\delta\to 0$, we have the form $\frac{0}{0}$ for the RHS above. By L'Hopital's Rule,
$$
p'(a)=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{f'(a+\delta)\delta-[f(a+\delta)-f(a)]}{\delta^2}=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\frac{f'(a+\delta)-\frac{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}{\delta}}{\delta}.
$$
By L'Hopital's Rule once more,
\begin{aligned}
p'(a)&=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left[f''(a+\delta)-\frac{f'(a+\delta)\delta-[f(a+\delta)-f(a)]}{\delta^2}\right]\\
&=f''(a)-\lim_{\delta\to 0}\left[\frac{f'(a+\delta)\delta-[f(a+\delta)-f(a)]}{\delta^2}\right]\\
&=f''(a)-p'(a)
\end{aligned}
implying that $p'(a)=\frac{1}{2}f''(a)$.

Comment: I think what you've done makes a lot of sense and is very much correct, but my lecturer said we had to incorporate Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @M.Byrne I'm going to sound stern here: so what if the problem isn't done the way your lecturer suggests? "Had to" doesn't seem like something a true teacher would say.

Comment: That is a fair point.  I found it weird as well because he said "Use the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem".  But what you did seems better.  Thank you @yunero!